# excel conditional formatting at least one

Tags: excel, format, conditional-statements

I have a need for conditional formatting in Excel.

I have 5 cols of data with either Yes or No in them

```
  A     B     C     D     E
1 Yes   No    No    No    No
2 No    Yes   No    No    No
3 No    No    No    Yes   No
```

I need to mark a row (or just a field)

```
 - if there is more than one Yes in a row
 - if there is no Yes in a row
```

How to?

Comment: How about something along the line of `=COUNTIF($A1:$E1,"yes")>0` and then copy it down to the rest of the rows?

Comment: @Clusks This option was already available in earlier versions of Excel. I know this because I used it to shade every other row in a different color (because back then there were no tables / ListObjects in Excel): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/268568

Comment: @Ralph I've always wondered about that, I just went off this link which says 2013 and 2016 at the top, so I presumed it wouldn't apply to older versions! https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Comment: =COUNTIF($N1:$S1;"yes")<1 makes the rows with no "Yes" in any fields marked.

Comment: But what if there is more than one "yes" in a row? Tried 
 
 
=COUNTIF($N1:$S1;"yes")>1 without result.

Comment: But if you attach the correct ranges ;-) It works.

Comment: @osomanden see my answer, if you use `=COUNTIF([formula])<>1` you can do it in one formula

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional formatting based on a formula, and for the formula put:

`=COUNTIF(1:1,"Yes")<>1`

That formula would be for the first row, then use format painter to paste the formatting onto every row.